# spring security3's protect pointcut is not working

Tags: spring

`<http > 
<intercept-url pattern="/a.jsp" access="hasRole('ROLE_X')"/> 
</http>`


in spring security3.0.7 or 3.1

it is Ok. only 'ROLE_X' can see a.jsp page.

but:
`<global-method-security  > 
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* test.Test.o1*(..))" access="hasRole('ROLE_X')"/> 
</global-method-security>`
  
it is not working,eneryone can use the method  test.Test.o1~~

when pre-post-annotations="enabled"
`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_X')")`
  
it is also not working,eneryone can use the method  test.Test.o1~~

i'm so sad~~
any advise or used 'global-method-security' demo , ths.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this annotation  in servlet config.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context

See also:
[Can Spring Security use @PreAuthorize on Spring controllers methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087548/can-spring-security-use-preauthorize-on-spring-controllers-methods)