# Spring Authorization via Annotations not working with custom Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsr250

I've overwritten the BasicAuthenticationFilter and replaced it with our a filter to fetch a custom Authentication object from db and set it via

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Here is the important fraction of the security config:

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="basicProcessingFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('user')"/>
</http>
<beans:bean id="authEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
</beans:bean>
<global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled"/>
```

I also provide my own AuthenticationProvider which simply is a no-op because the authentication process is already done in the custom filter:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    logger.info("user:" + authentication.getPrincipal() + " pw:" + authentication.getCredentials());
    authentication.setAuthenticated(false);        
    return authentication;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
    return MyAuthentication.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
}
```

Now, Spring correctly prints the required role(s) for every method on start, so it detects the annotations correctly. E.g. the 'admin' role for a delete method:

2011-11-22 11:47:09,474 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource - Adding security method [CacheKey[com.somecompany.SomeClass; public  com.somecompany.ReturnType com.somecompany.SomeClass.delete()]] with attributes [admin]

**But Spring does not check somehow if the user has this role.** Instead it falls back to the global pattern defined in the http tag of the security context xml file. So, e.g. if I access this delete method with a user of roles:["user"] it will accept it because of the hasRole('user') in the http tag.

Probably it is something wrong when initializing the DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource object because it won't be filled with a specific rule for the delete method!? Only the http-tag defined rules are added via the addSecureUrl method.

**What could be wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving

```
<global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled"/>
```

from spring security context to the context where I 'scanned' the classes (i.e. my application context) helped. Thanks to comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3087646/194609)