# SpringSecurity. @PreAuthorize is not working

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Spring Security use @PreAuthorize on Spring controllers methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087548/can-spring-security-use-preauthorize-on-spring-controllers-methods)

Here is my configuration:
pom.xml

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- AOP dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- end of Spring Security -->
```

here is security.xml ->

```
    <!-- secured-annotations = (@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")) -->
    <!-- jsr250-annotations = (@RunAs @RolesAllowed @PermitAll @DenyAll @DeclareRoles) -->
    <!-- pre-post-annotations = @PreAuthorized("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')") -->

<global-method-security secured-annotations="disabled"
                        jsr250-annotations="disabled"
                        pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<http       auto-config='true' 
            disable-url-rewriting="true" 
            access-denied-page="/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/accessDenied.jsp">


    <anonymous granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" key="anonymous"/>


    <logout logout-url="/logout.do" logout-success-url="/" />

    <form-login always-use-default-target="false" 
        authentication-failure-url="/?authfailed=true" 
        default-target-url="/person"
        login-page="/" 
        login-processing-url="/login"
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password" 
         />

      <remember-me key="rememberMe" services-ref="rememberMeService"/>
</http>
```

When I try run any controller like ->

@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

```
@RequestMapping("")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public String root() {
    doStuff();
    return "redirect:/person/home";
}
```

with any different role, I got right result.  so @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')") annotation is not working.

No compilation mistakes, no runtime exceptions.

Thanks.

Comment: " your controller is likely situated in servlet context, while the method interceptor declared in the root context" - please explain better - what you actually mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring method interceptors (spring AOP) work only in  bounds of the contexts where they were declared

Comment: do you have the spring-aop dependency ?