# Securing controller method with @RolesAllowed and @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I've been banging my head over this one for a while now. I've done everything I could in order to find an appropriate solution and followed a lot of Stackoverflow examples and solutions.

First, I'm using annotation based solution. When I annotate my services, prePostEnabled works, but not when I annotate the controllers, it doesn't. Also, even on my services, jsr250Enabled doesn't work.

I've found a lot of case closed by moving the annotation from the security config to the MVC config, which in my case doesn't work.

I've a setup that looks like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth-javaconfig/tree/master/samples/oauth2-sparklr

But I use Servlet 3.0 and doesn't have anything in my web.xml.

My SecurityInitializer looks like this:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

My MVC initializer looks like this:

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebSecurityConfig.class, MethodSecurityConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{SpringMvcConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{ApiPaths.API + "/*", "/res.jsp"};
}
```

My WebSecurity config is initialized like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.roler.res.**.server"}, excludeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = SpringMvcConfig.class),
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MethodSecurityConfig.class),
    @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.xyz.*.controller.*")})
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

And my SpringMvcConfig is initialized like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = "com.xyz.**.controller")
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

If you have any ideas, I'm out of juice, Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symptoms you describe make me think to a problem of proxying. Annotations works fine on service layer, because services generally implements interfaces, and Spring can easily use a JDK proxy to put the AOP authorizations.

But controllers generally do not implement interfaces. That's the reason why PreAuthorize annotation are more frequently used in service layer. IMHO, you'd better try to use URL pattern based authorization instead of PreAuthorize annotations on controller. The alternative would be to use target class proxying with CGLIB.

To use `PreAuthorize` and JSR-250 annotations, you must

- annotate you spring security configuration class with :

  ```
  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
  ```
- if you use anywhere else in your application Spring AOP with JDK proxies, make all controller classes in which you want to use method security implement interfaces declaring all protected methods
- if you use anywhere else in your application Spring AOP with CGLIB proxies, add `proxyTargetClass = true` to `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` :

  ```
  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true,
          proxyTargetClass = true)
  ```
- if you want to use CGLIB proxies with Spring version under 3.2, add CGLIB library to your classpath (CGLIB classes are included in Spring 3.2+)
- avoid mixing CGLIB and JDK proxying as it is not recommended by Spring documentation : *Multiple  sections are collapsed into a single unified auto-proxy creator at runtime, which applies the strongest proxy settings that any of the  sections (typically from different XML bean definition files) specified. This also applies to the  and  elements.*
  *To be clear: using 'proxy-target-class="true"' on ,  or  elements will force the use of CGLIB proxies for all three of them.*

But anyway, my advice is to try to move method security to service layer which normally already supports AOP.

Comment: Through @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity, but my priority is still to get annotations on Controllers as I have also system functionalities that uses my service layer.

Also URL pattern could be fine, but I also need to validate some information contained "inside" and I want to use AoP to validate those seamlessly across the system.

Comment: @ChristianGoudreau : Post edited with configuration precisions.

Comment: Well, adding proxyTargetClass for my configuration makes my ldap configuration fails since it's not within WebSecurityConfig. It says: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer@553d70ce to already built object

Comment: @ChristianGoudreau : it's not really a surprise. That's the reason why I said to use `proxyTargetClass=true` if you already used CGLIB proxies and to not mix different proxy modes. You are left with only 2 options : migrate method security to service layer or make your controllers implement interfaces to allow JDK proxying.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed (as mentioned on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087548/can-spring-security-use-preauthorize-on-spring-controllers-methods?rq=1)):

1. prePostEnabled in the annotation to enable Pre/Post annotations
2. use of CGLib proxies (Serge mentioned this too)

Does your @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity have those two attributes?

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
```