# PreAuthorize not working on Controller

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I'm trying to define access rules at method-level but it's not working what so ever.

SecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and().
                withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("Secure api")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

ExampleController

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/v2/"})
public class ExampleController {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to access /v2/home using `user:user` it executes just fine, shouldn't it give me an Access Denied error due to 'user' not having `ROLE_ADMIN`?

I'm actually thinking of ditching access rules at method-level and stick to http() ant rules, but I have to know why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A common problem with using PrePost annotations on controllers is that Spring method security is based on Spring AOP, which is by default implemented with JDK proxies.

That means that it works fine on the service layer which is injected in controller layer as interfaces, but it is ignored on controller layer because controller generally do not implement interfaces.

The following is just my opinion:

- prefered way: move the pre post annotation on service layer
- if you cannot (or do not want to), try to have your controller implement an interface containing all the annotated methods
- as a last way, use *proxy-target-class=true*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried using the annotation on a `CrudRepository` interface  and it worked fine. Having an interface to each  controller is kinda silly in my opinion as an interface isn't really necessary. `proxy-target-class=true` didn't make a difference, the annotations still doesn't work on controllers, however it caused a crash (while set to true) when having the annotation inside the repository interface (Cannot subclass com.sun.proxy). Anyway I think I'm going to stick to rules in the security config, and maybe use PreAuth on some of my repositories.

Comment: One other thing that I noticed, I've seen examples where the @PreAuthorize was used in a `class` instead of an `interface` and it's supposed to be working.. I wonder why it works for them but not for me.

Comment: Enable Aop in application context <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

Comment: Adding the interface fixed it for me, but another project doesn't have interfaces, and the controller methods are protected.  There must be some other configuration that they're using that I'm not.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but opposite. @PreAuthorize works normal on controller layer but not on service layer. Do you know why?

Comment: I had weird problems using @PreAuthorize on Controller: some applications works well and some applications don't.

Comment: has this been changed by now? Because the prePost annotations work absolutely fine on my controllers without implementing any interface or allowing target class proxying

Answer (score 96):

You have to add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` in your WebSecurityConfig.

You can find it here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Comment: Also per previous commenter if putting pre/post on a controller method that does not implement an interface also add annotation property  `proxyTargetClass = true` to `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125388/preauthorize-not-working-with-prepostenabled-true).

Comment: Worked for me, although the annotation has since become deprecated, this is the currently non-deprecated one: @EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

Answer (score 17):

put `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` into MvcConfig class (extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter) instead of (extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter).

Like below example:-

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem and the following solved it:

1) I had to make my method public (i.e. make your method home() public)

2) I have to use hasRole instead of hasAuthority

Answer (score 11):

For those coming here in 2023 and beyond, you must add the `@EnableMethodSecurity` annotation to your configuration class. It's also worth noting that Spring Boot also uses Auto Configuration as of 2023. An example security configuration is included below.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity // Add this
public class SecurityConfig {
    // Add your configuration Beans here
}
```

And your controller should look something like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController
{
    // Replace this with your service or other means to fetch resources
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    // Note: I am using a scope called "users.read" below, but you can use
    // ROLE_<role_name> if you are using roles instead.
    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users.read')")
    public List<UserDto> listUsers()
    {
        return userRepository.findAllBy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, on 2023 May 2nd day, @EnableMethodSecurity is the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

There are two different ways to use this, one is to prefix and one is not.
And you maybe change `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")` to `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")` will be ok.

next is `@PreAuthorize` source code.

```
private String defaultRolePrefix = "ROLE_";
public final boolean hasAuthority(String authority) {
    return hasAnyAuthority(authority);
}

public final boolean hasAnyAuthority(String... authorities) {
    return hasAnyAuthorityName(null, authorities);
}

public final boolean hasRole(String role) {
    return hasAnyRole(role);
}

public final boolean hasAnyRole(String... roles) {
    return hasAnyAuthorityName(defaultRolePrefix, roles);
}
```

Comment: and this source should be added where and how does my controller access it ?

Comment: The problem of the ExampleController, only changed ROLE_ADMIN to ADMIN

Comment: I tried as you suggested it works fine,  but what is the correct way of implementing `hasRole` clause like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue while trying to authorize AD Group of user
these steps worked for me

1. `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` on class which is annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity`
2. Created custom(GroupUserDetails) UserDetails which will have userName and authorities and return the instance of GroupUserDetails from custome UserDetailsService
3. Annotate controller method with

   `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Group-Name')")`

Answer (score 3):

For making it working on controller layer.
I had to put `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on my configuration class.
Example :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.fraud.ts.userservices.web.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

}
```

Comment: mine worked without this @EnableAspectJAutoProxy I just used @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")

Comment: why is that? @kripal kashyav

Answer (score 3):

My Controller`s methods were private they need to be public.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a xml context file for your security beans and a separate one for your web/servlet context, than you als need to add:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

to your web-context.xml / servlet context. Its not enough to just add it in the security context xml.

Its not inherited in child contexts.

HTH

Comment: OP did it already using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Answer (score 1):

your request method is `protected` by default. So they can't scan it. Set it `public`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the controller menthod from `private` to `public` and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

June 2023 :
For those who are still struggling:
**SecurityConfig**

```
 @Bean
   public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
           
           UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("user123"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

           return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin,user);
    }
```

Your **Controller** should be like:

```
@GetMapping("/getAll")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    public List<Student> findAllStudents() {
        return studentServiceI.findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a static keyword in the method, by removing this, the @Preauthorize worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.anyRequest().authenticated()` in `authorizeRequest()` for HttpSecurity object.

because the default HttpBuilder implementation is still active, and because it’s assessed during the web request filter chain, it takes precedence.

by `authorizeRequest.anyRequest().authenticated()` you’ve done is use SecurityConfig class to explicitly permit all requests on the home endpoint while requiring authentication on all other endpoints. This sets a blanket minimum authentication requirement for your app. You also re-enabled form-based authentication.