# implementing an interface contains @PreAuthorize to a controller causes something wrong, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have this `Controller` and an `Interface`, when i try to implement the interface for applying `Preauthorize` annotation , it cause a damage to the controller , so the `methods` aren't working at that case . I know that i can apply the annotation directly inside the `controller` but i'll be happy if i can apply it using the interface as read in Spring's example

```
public interface PermissionsSecurity {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    String deletePost(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    String permissions(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) String q);
}
```

**Controller :**

```
@Controller
public class PermissionsController implements PermissionsSecurity{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("permissionValidator")
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    private Permissions permissionsService;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinber(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/permissions:delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deletePost(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id) {
        permissionsService.delete(id);

        return "redirect:/permissions";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/permissions", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String permissions(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) String q){
        model.addAttribute("q", (q != null)? q : "");
        model.addAttribute("viewTemplate", "permissions");
        model.addAttribute("roles", permissionsService.getAll());

        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do it like that... Put them on the class not an interface (basically inheritance of annotations from interfaces to classes isn't supported, spring uses a work around to make it work, interfaces like this use proxies which in turn lead to issues with the request mapping. You need to force the use of class based proxies instead of interface based proxies to make it work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Regarding the `@Service` permissionsService ? that contains the repository interface, Should i add put `@Preauthorize ` on it ? or it's enough to seure the methods only ? what's the correct security logic ?

Comment: I found an answer for this question. * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442408/preauthorize-not-working-on-controller