# Service layer security or web request (controller layer) security, which one is better?

Tags: spring-security

When implementing a web project using Spring security, a question I encounter is in which layer the security logic should be implemented?

In [Spring Security Reference 15.5.1 General Questions - 2. Why not just use web.xml security?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-faq-web-xml), it appears to recommend using service layer security. I list some scenarios where they are not easy to resolve in service layer so I think that service layer may not always be the best approach.

Suppose there is a request handler will involve three services calls: S1, S2, S3, with each service requiring different permissions.

1. Compared to performing security checks in the controller/view layer, it is possible that S1 and S2 succeed, and the last call to S3 failed duo to permission issue, it can introduce a partial failure issue due to permission constraints.
2. Building upon the previous point, if the S3 service method is executed in a separate thread, the end-users may not receive a response promptly, potentially affecting the customer experience.
3. When dealing with different sources of requests (e.g., client, web browser), varying  permissions may be required for different request sources. How can we implement permission checks in service layer?

Comment: first of all, the documentation you are referring to is 5.1, spring security 6 was released about a year ago so please read up to date documentation instead. Second `it appears to recommend using service layer security.` i do not see this recommendation anywhere, please show more exact where this recommendation is stated.

Comment: The latest reference doc is only 5.x. If you read it carefully, you would see **An MVC controller or view is simply the incorrect architectural layer to implement authorization decisions concerning services layer methods or domain object instances.** @Toerktumlare

Comment: Im not going to chase through the text to find what you should of included in your question. The latest reference doc is not 5.x https://spring.io/projects/spring-security/#learn it is 6.1.4 and their recommendation is that you dont implement authorization concerns in the controllers about things that is deeper. For instance you dont make decisions in the controller who is allowed to write to what table in the database.

Comment: You are right, The change in document style made me misunderstand that some parts of the document are missing. However, the content was the same in the latest version 6.x. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/appendix/faq.html#appendix-faq-web-xml

Comment: and i still dont understand your question they explain it clearly `An MVC controller or view is the incorrect architectural layer in which to implement authorization decisions concerning services layer methods or domain object instances. While the principal may be passed to the services layer to enable it to make the authorization decision, doing so would introduce an additional argument on every services layer method.` This means that you would need to in every single function you need to pass around the principal, so they instead pass it in thread local.

Comment: I still dont see where spring security are favoring service layer security over controller layer security. There is no such claim anywhere in the text.

Comment: also `MVC controllers or views that implement authorization code makes it more difficult to test both the controller and the authorization logic, is more difficult to debug, and often leads to code duplication.` so there you go. There is your answer.