# Can a Spring Security annotation affect the dispatch of a Spring MVC call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Let's say that I have a @Controller with two methods that do related but different things. I want to expose them on the same URL endpoint but have different functionality depending on the security context. Now I know that I could have a single mapped request method and dispatch to different utility functions within my class, but could I wire it so that Spring MVC will handle the dispatch for me based on what comes in?

As a strawman example, there's code that dispatches between ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER, but my actual use case is a good chunk more complicated:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/api/thing")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String doAnAdministrativeThing() {
         ... (admin-priviledge stuff goes here)
    }

    @RequestMapping("/api/thing")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String doADifferentThing() {
         ... (normal-priviledged stuff goes here)
    }

}
```

To preempt any rabbit holes:

1. No, I might not have any choice about having the two functions be on different URLs or having different parameters or any of the "normal" @RequestMapping bits
2. The security context differences are complex but can be processed within a @PreAuthorize expression
3. There are actually more than two different contexts to dispatch on

Answer (score 2):

I think that this will not work, global method security has absolutely nothing to do with MVC layer. 
Moreover it's officially recommended to use method security [only for the service layer](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context)

> Generally we would recommend applying method security at the service
>   layer rather than on individual web controllers.

P.S. generally I try to avoid using AOP with Spring controllers, and declare AOP methods  only in the root context(and not in the servlet context), because proxying controller instance can lead to some confusing behavior, and forces the users to know Spring AOP specific things, like difference between JDK proxy and CGLIB proxy, how annotations are processed, etc.

Comment: This was the impression that I was getting from the documentation, but it seemed like such a useful pattern that I wanted to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will work with some extensions. See the reference to [GitHub mohchi / spring-security-request-mapping](https://github.com/mohchi/spring-security-request-mapping) in @andy's answer to [Can Spring Security use @PreAuthorize on Spring controllers methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087548/can-spring-security-use-preauthorize-on-spring-controllers-methods)

Comment: This is very interesting, and seems to be exactly what I was looking to do. I wish it were packaged as a module that we could simply incorporate.