# Custom validation for all the query of spring rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-security

I am using Spring Rest API, and i want to apply custom validation (To be more specific, i want to check user authenticated or not so for that i need `HttpServletRequest` object also) before going inside the rest api query.

For example, I have 3 APIs.
1. RestAPI/test1
2. RestAPI/test2
3. RestAPI/test3

so before doing the query, I want to check that user is authenticated or not.

Can i use `ConstraintValidator`?

How can i achieve this?

I am not using spring boot...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are following ways to do it:

1) Spring security `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` or `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")`

See the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087548/can-spring-security-use-preauthorize-on-spring-controllers-methods) for more info

2) You can create custom annotation, add aspect with `SecurityContextHolder` check in it :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Authenticated {
}

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthenticatedAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(Authenticated)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
         if (!SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()) {
             throw your exeption
         }
         return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

For second approach you probably need to add `proxy-target-class="true"`
     `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`